No way to limit concurrency in node?
I've been looking for a way to do this:
Instead of:
await myfunc()
I want to:
limiter = Limiter(50)
await limiter(myfunc)

The Limiter won't add my function to the event queue and, instead, will block (yield to other callers), if 50 of my function calls are pending
In this way, the system will gracefully degrade when busy, propagating resource issues to the client.
I looked into using semaphores and mutexes, but they don't exist, and the libraries for them have the same problem (infinite promises... each caller waiting on a semaphore creates a new promise to happen later).
This is my solution, is it ok?
class Limiter {
    constructor(maxConcurrent) {
        this.maxConcurrent = maxConcurrent;
        this.currentCount = 0;
        this.waitingResolvers = [];
    }

    async acquire() {
        if (this.currentCount < this.maxConcurrent) {
            this.currentCount++;
        } else {
            await new Promise(resolve => this.waitingResolvers.push(resolve));
        }
    }

    release() {
        if (this.waitingResolvers.length > 0) {
            const resolve = this.waitingResolvers.shift();
            resolve();
        } else {
            this.currentCount--;
        }
    }

    async run(task, ...args) {
        await this.acquire();
        task(...args).then(this.release.bind(this),this.release.bind(this));
    }
}


Usage:
limiter = new Limiter(50);
# only blocks if there are more than 50 running
await limiter.run(myFunc);


You are probably looking for rate limiting strategy called leaky bucket. Here is neat npm package that implements this trick. github with the source code.
Example:
const bucket = new Bucket({
    capacity: 60,
});

await Promise.all(items.map(async(item) => {
    await bucket.throttle();
    myfunc(item);
}));


i want to schedule a promise... unless there's too many, then it should block (yield) until available.   it's not in a loop.   i checked out your suggestion - it just throws an exception when there's too many.   not really useful.
